# PYTHON - Armazenamento de valores, linha por linha, em txt

Tags: python, txt, armazenamento

Como faço para armazenar valores diferentes, linha por linha, em um arquivo txt sem que exclua o anterior?

Comment: Inclua o seu código à pergunta

Answer (score 1):

Você usa o `a` de *append* no `open` e soma com o `\n` o \n faz pular uma linha.
Então seria algo como

```
teste = 'linha um' + '\n'
arq = open('arquivo.txt','a')
arq.write(teste)
arq.write('123'+'\n')
```

Normalmente se usa uma lista, e se roda um for, mudando o parâmetro do `.write` 
Um exemplo mais extenso:

```
def cadastrar():
    nome   = raw_input('INFORME O NOME DO CLIENTE: ')
    cpf    = raw_input('INFORME O CPF DO CLIENTE: ')
    senha  = raw_input('INFORME A UMA NOVA SENHA: ')
    saldo  = raw_input('INFORME CASO EXISTA SALDO INICIAL: ')

    arq = open('clientes/' + cpf + '.txt', 'w')
    arq.write(nome+'\n')
    arq.write(cpf+'\n')
    arq.write(senha+'\n')
    if saldo != '':
        arq.write(saldo+'\n')
    arq.close()
```

Versão do python: 2.7